# Form Validation not working AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to do form validation using AngularJS in Laravel Blade, but it isn't working and when clicked on the submit button **`undefined`** gets printed in the console.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="uk-grid" ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <form name="signupForm" class="uk-form uk-width-1-2" novalidate>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <fieldset class="pad50">
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <input class="bradius2" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" ng-modal="user.username" required>
        <div ng-show="signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.username.$touched">
          <span ng-show="signupForm.username.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <input class="bradius2" placeholder="Email" type="email" name="user_mail" ng-modal="user.user_mail" required>
        <div ng-show="signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.user_mail.$touched">
          <span ng-show="signupForm.user_mail.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
          <span ng-show="signupForm.user_mail.$error.email">Enter a valid email.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <input class="bradius2" placeholder="Password" type="password" name="user_pass" ng-modal="user.user_pass" required>
        <div ng-show="signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.user_pass.$touched">
          <span ng-show="signupForm.user_pass.$error.required">Password is required</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <input class="bradius2" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password" name="user_cpass" ng-modal="user.user_cpass" required>
        <div ng-show="signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.user_cpass.$touched">
          <span ng-show="signupForm.user_cpass.$error.required">Confirm the password</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-form-row">
        <button class="uk-button bgorange butn uk-button-large" type="submit" id="sign_up_button" ng-click="signupUser(user)">
          <b>SIGN UP VIA EMAIL</b>
        </button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('validationApp', [])
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.signupUser = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        console.log(user);
    };

}]);
```

I am using Angular version 1.6.1 and also UIKit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has to be ng-model instead of ng-modal. 
ng-model is the one which stores the user input in form.

Answer (score 1):

> **undefined** gets printed in the console

you need to initialize the `user` object

```
angular.module('validationApp', [])
.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.master = {};
     $scope.user = {};// here
    $scope.signupUser = function(user) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(user);
        console.log(user);
    };
}]);
```

> Form Validation not working AngularJS

You should add this code on your form tag

`ng-submit="mainForm.$valid && yourfunction()"` //yourfunction means which event you want to be fire

Comment: user needn't actually be initialised. user is already an object used in form. And all those sub-values already get stored in $scope.user. like $scope.user={c_mail:something, c_pass:something} and so on. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Nope. If you didn't fill anything in the form fields. it will consider like as undefined object  does make sense gayu? :p

Comment: Thank you for the `ng-submit` tip

Comment: No you arenot. In presence of validation, it'll prompt to fill required fields and without validation, it'll be just blank null. And moreover, it's nested json that would be already be created in the end on submit. And there's no need to initialise $scope.user={ }

Answer (score 0):

notice ng-messages:

```
    <div class="uk-form-row" >
        <input class="bradius2" placeholder="Username" type="text" name="username" ng-model="user.username" required>
        <div ng-messages="signupForm.username.$error" ng-show="signupForm.$submitted || signupForm.username.$touched">
      <span ng-show="signupForm.username.$error.required">Username is required.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
```